# Why to use @property in iOS app development

Tags: ios, properties, using-directives

I searched on internet about the @property in iOS and got answers such no need to explicitly use setter and getter method. beside all these answer can u explain me what is exact benefit of using @propert in iOS app development.

what its benefit and when to use?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Basics of OOP(Object Oriented Programming) -  You hide all ivars / properties to outside world.

`@property` is specific to Objective-C, which creates ivars and you are given an option either to use compiler defined setter & getter, or create your own by `@synthesize`.

Few differences still valid for Objective-C and other OOP languages like ivars/properties are private/protected/public. There are ways to set its access-specifiers.

If you are fancied about ivars and properties one of the major advantage is of KVO (Key Value Observer) this helps you to minimize your codes and only `self.property` name suffice.